# Computational cost, power method and page rank

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

When solving the PageRank problem for $n$ web pages, it is necessary to find a solution of the eigenvector equation 
$$(fM)*p = p,$$ 
where
$$fM = dM + (1 - d)Z$$ $$Z =\frac{1}{n}*ee^T$$
$$e =[1, 1, 1, 1, 1,\dots]^T$$
and $0<d<1$.

1. When the power method is used to solve $(fM)*p = p$, iterates are given by $p(k) = (fM)*p(k-1)$. How
   should $p(k)$ be formed efficiently, and at what computational cost (using  to denote the number of nonzeros in $M$)?
2. Use $(I -dM)p =(\frac{1-d}{n})e$ and MATLAB backslash to solve the system.

So I think I should use the fM definition and equate it to $(I -dM)p =(\frac{1-d}{n})e$ but then I'm not sure how to then use the power method on it and what the computational cost would be.

2.So my code for this part doesnt seem to match up the answer with my power method. It's not even close. Have I done something wrong. 
Here is the code:

```
d=0;
e=ones(n,1);
a=1/n;
Z=a*(e*e');
Mtilda=d*M+(1-d)*Z;
g=((1-d)/n)*e;
k=(eye(n))-(d*M);
p2=(g\k);
```

Comment: When I was trying to solve pagerank systems in Matlab I want to say that I used the "sparse" command pretty frequently to make it less computationally expensive.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean or where you would put this command

Comment: BTW you say that $0<d<1$ and then set $d=0$.

Comment: The question in point 2 reads: "Use ...some relation... and MATLAB backslash to solve the system." The question is: what system? There's no system here except an eigenvalue problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the system.  This assumes your data is in a separate file.
I used mine on one that had over 800,000 entries and it worked.
We were also looking for time to compute and not outputting the explicit answer, so if it is inaccurate I apologize.
Ours was given as 
$v^T=v^TG$ if and only if $(I-\alpha H^T)x=u$ and $v=x/\|x\|_1$.
So in MATLAB:

```
clear all; load file;
t0=clock();  %start time
m=length(H); 
C=sparse(H); %stores nonzero entries of H by location
I=speye(size(H)); %Identity same size as H
q=0.85; %this is alpha, d I believe in your notation  
e=(ones(m,1));
u=e/m;
P=I-q*C';
G=sparse(P);
y=G*u;
elapsed_time=etime(clock(),t0)
```

You should just need to retrieve y.

Comment: If you are using large data sets and do not use sparse it will never finish unless you are using a rather amazing machine.  The one I was using at the time would crash whenever I tried just because I forgot to sparse P.